# Flutter how to add a 0 behind a hour if the hour is less than 10?

Tags: flutter, hour

Im trying to check if an hour is below 10 so i can add a 0 behind it to make it the right hour format.
All my efforts till now haven't worked out.
Thank you for you time

Comment: Postvyour current code. Also you need zero added in front.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [padLeft()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/String/padLeft.html) method on strings. It takes `width` and `padding` parameters. You can use it like this:

```
print("5".padLeft(2,"0")); // Prints 05

print("14".padLeft(2,"0")); // Prints 14
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this;

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
String newHour = now.hour.toString();
if (newHour.length > 2) {
  newHour = "0"+ newHour;
}
```